# Automatically indexing digraphs as single letters

Tags: indexing, languages

I'm working on a document that contains many older Danish names and places, from when Å was still the Aa-digraph. I want these entries to sort correctly, ie. in the order A..Z Æ Ø Aa/Å.

Looking in the `imakeidx` documentation I haven't found anything, neither in the search here. If some other package solves it, that is fine.

I am aware that I could use something like `\index{Åge@Aage}` to sort `Aage` as if it was spelled `Åge`, but the full document I'm working on creates the index entries based on other variables fairly deeply in the code, and I don't see a good simple way of detecting and changing the entries on the fly. I would like to just sort the entries as described with the least amount of fuss.

Note also that Ø is sorted after Å for some reason, this is incorrect in Danish.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\makeindex

\newcommand\indexed[1]{#1\index{#1}}

\begin{document}

The entries should come in this order:

\indexed{Abel}
\indexed{Anders}

\indexed{Hans}
\indexed{Haagen}

\indexed{Karen}
\indexed{Karsten}
\indexed{Kaare}

\indexed{Lærke}

\indexed{Øjvind}

\indexed{Aage}
\indexed{Åse}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use xindy  that can sort out based on a sorting alphabet. Quick hack, `\index{z1@Øjvind}`
`\index{z2@Åse}`. You will also do this for   æ.  Since danish has only 3 problematic macro you can write custom macros for the 3.

Comment: upmendex  also can do sorting as per custom sorting orders. I havent really used it though.

Comment: As mentioned, the `\index` entries in my full document are assembled from variables, I don't write them by hand directly in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call indexing processor with support for Danish, which can be either Xindy or Xindex. It seems that `imakeidx` supports only `xindy`. You can use it with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
%\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\makeindex[program=truexindy,options={-M texindy -C utf8 -L danish}]

\newcommand\indexed[1]{#1\index{#1}}

\begin{document}

The entries should come in this order:

\indexed{Abel}
\indexed{Anders}

\indexed{Hans}
\indexed{Haagen}

\indexed{Karen}
\indexed{Karsten}
\indexed{Kaare}

\indexed{Lærke}

\indexed{Øjvind}

\indexed{Aage}
\indexed{Åse}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Compile using:

```
$ lualatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

This is the resulting index:

[image]